# Flutter RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fetching data from my api previously i am suing hardcoded json data so its working perfectly in app but now when i am using the API data its showing this error

RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool showApp = false;
   var _questions = new List<Questions>();
  _getQuestions() {
    API.getUsers().then((response) {
      setState(() {

        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        print(list);
        print(list);
        _questions = list.map((model) => Questions.fromJson(model)).toList();
        print(_questions);
        showApp = true;
      });
    });
  }
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getQuestions();
  }

  int index = 0;
  bool shouldShow = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    int size = _questions.length;

    void nextQuestion() {
      if (index < size - 1)
        setState(() {
          index++;
        });
      print(index);
    }

    double percentage1Calculate() {
      int wouldClick = 12;
      int ratherClick = 13;
      double percentage1 = wouldClick / (wouldClick + ratherClick) * 100;
      return percentage1;
    }

    double percentage2Calculate() {
      int wouldClick = 2;
      int ratherClick = 3;
      double percentage2 = ratherClick / (wouldClick + ratherClick) * 100;
      return percentage2;
    }

    void percengtageTrigger(){
      setState(() {
        shouldShow = true;
      });
      Timer timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1350), () {
        setState(() {
          shouldShow = false;
        });
      });
    }

    final PrimaryColor = const Color(0xff404040);

    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        'Would you Rather',
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'FredokaOne'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
    );
    double stackHeight = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        appBar.preferredSize.height -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top);
    double stackWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff404040),
        appBar: appBar,


        body: Stack(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                percengtageTrigger();
              },
              child: Container(
                height: stackHeight * 0.5,
                width: stackWidth,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    shouldShow
                        ? Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 10),
                        height: stackHeight * 0.1,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              '${percentage1Calculate().toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 23,
                                fontFamily: 'NewsCycle',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ))
                        : Container(
                      height: stackHeight * 0.1,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      width: double.infinity,
                    ),
                    Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        height: stackHeight * 0.4,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                              child: Text(
                                _questions[index].would, //here its showing error 
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 23,
                                  fontFamily: 'NewsCycle',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                percengtageTrigger();
              },
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  height: stackHeight * 0.5,
                  width: stackWidth,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      shouldShow
                          ? Container(
                          padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 10),
                          height: stackHeight * 0.1,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                '${percentage2Calculate().toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 23,
                                  fontFamily: 'NewsCycle',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ))
                          : Container(
                        height: stackHeight * 0.1,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        width: double.infinity,
                      ),
                      Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          height: stackHeight * 0.4,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                                child: Text(
                                  _questions[index].rather,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 23,
                                    fontFamily: 'NewsCycle',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Container(
                width: stackWidth,
                height: stackHeight * 0.015,
                color: Color(0xff404040),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Container(
                  width: stackWidth,
                  height: stackHeight * 0.15,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Color(0xff404040),
                  ),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        nextQuestion();
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "SKIP",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'FredokaOne',
                            fontSize: 27),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Also comment in code where its showing error. I dont know how to solve it but i think the issue is causing because API data is not loaded before its calling the index data maybe ?

Try to use Futurebuild function but its just keep loading the function and showing the indicator not showing the Container when its loaded in termail its keep printing the value as infinite loop.

```
 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool showApp = false;
  var _questions = new List<Questions>();

  Future<List> _getQuestions() async {
    final response = await API.getUsers();
    setState(() {
      Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
      print(list);
      print(list);
      _questions = list.map((model) => Questions.fromJson(model)).toList();
      print(_questions);
      showApp = true;
    });
    return Future.value(_questions);
  }

  int index = 0;
  bool shouldShow = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int size = _questions?.length;

    void nextQuestion() {
      if (index < size - 1)
        setState(() {
          index++;
        });
      print(index);
    }

    double percentage1Calculate() {
      int wouldClick = 12;
      int ratherClick = 13;
      double percentage1 = wouldClick / (wouldClick + ratherClick) * 100;
      return percentage1;
    }

    double percentage2Calculate() {
      int wouldClick = 2;
      int ratherClick = 3;
      double percentage2 = ratherClick / (wouldClick + ratherClick) * 100;
      return percentage2;
    }

    void percengtageTrigger() {
      setState(() {
        shouldShow = true;
      });
      Timer timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1350), () {
        setState(() {
          shouldShow = false;
        });
      });
    }

    final PrimaryColor = const Color(0xff404040);

    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        'Would you Rather',
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'FredokaOne'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
    );
    double stackHeight = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        appBar.preferredSize.height -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top);
    double stackWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return FutureBuilder(
        initialData: null, //initial default data if you have some
        future: _getQuestions(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print("Data found, You can continue");
              return Center(child: Text('Datafound'));
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text('HaSError'));
            }
          } else {
            print("loading");
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: int size = _questions?.length; can you try this?

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya not working

Comment: In your code with FutureBuilder version, you need to move all unrelated with widget creation from your `Widget build(BuildContext context)`. 
Then in your  `Future<List> _getQuestions() async` method, remove `setState` and you only need to return  `_questions` **not** `Future.value(_questions);`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is what you are suspecting. The data is not available before the build method starts executing and thus we are encountering an out of range error. The solution to this problem would be to use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) in your build method.

Instead of getting the data in initState, wrap the code inside your build method in `FutureBuilder` and set the `getUser()` as the `future` parameter in the `FutureBuilder`. Take a look the code snippet below

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        initialData:null //initial default data if you have some
        future: API.getUsers(),
        builder:(BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            if(snapshot.ConnectionState==ConnectionState.none||snapshot.ConnectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
                print("data has not been fetched yet");
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            else{
             if(snapshot.hasData){
                 print("Data found, You can continue");
                 //decode your json here and initialize the variables you need
                 return Scaffold(
                     // your widgets
                 );
             }else{
                 print("No data found");
                 return Text("No data found");
             }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

In your case, you'd do something like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool showApp = false;
  var _questions = new List<Questions>();

  // Future<List> _getQuestions() async {
  //   final response = await API.getUsers();
  //   setState(() {
  //     Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
  //     print(list);
  //     print(list);
  //     _questions = list.map((model) => Questions.fromJson(model)).toList();
  //     print(_questions);
  //     showApp = true;
  //   });
  //   return Future.value(_questions);
  // }

  int index = 0;
  bool shouldShow = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int size = _questions?.length;

    void nextQuestion() {
      if (index < size - 1)
        setState(() {
          index++;
        });
      print(index);
    }

    double percentage1Calculate() {
      int wouldClick = 12;
      int ratherClick = 13;
      double percentage1 = wouldClick / (wouldClick + ratherClick) * 100;
      return percentage1;
    }

    double percentage2Calculate() {
      int wouldClick = 2;
      int ratherClick = 3;
      double percentage2 = ratherClick / (wouldClick + ratherClick) * 100;
      return percentage2;
    }

    void percengtageTrigger() {
      setState(() {
        shouldShow = true;
      });
      Timer timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1350), () {
        setState(() {
          shouldShow = false;
        });
      });
    }

    final PrimaryColor = const Color(0xff404040);

    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        'Would you Rather',
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'FredokaOne'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
    );
    double stackHeight = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        appBar.preferredSize.height -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top);
    double stackWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return FutureBuilder(
        initialData: null, //initial default data if you have some
        future: API.getUsers(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              var response  = snapshot.data;
              print("Data found, You can continue");
              Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
              print(list);
              print(list);
              _questions =
                  list.map((model) => Questions.fromJson(model)).toList();
              print(_questions);
              showApp = true;
              return Center(child: Text('Datafound'));
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text('HaSError'));
            }
          } else {
            print("loading");
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i try this but its just keep loading the future function and printing the value and indicatore is showing but after loading the data not showing the container. I have added my code in end of question

Comment: I think that's because you are calling setState In the _getQuestion method. This will make the build method execute again and again. Try moving the code from getUsers future to inside the builder method of future builder just above the return statement for snapshot.hasData.And don't forget to remove the setState. You won't need it.

Comment: I update by question i read the documentation and now i doing like this but still just loading the indicator and values of questions

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code snippet to show how to do it. Please take a look. I've removed the _getQuestions function and moved the content appropriately inside the builder method of the future.